# Scrapy, сигнал о завершении

Tags: python, scrapy

Можно ли как-то проверить, что паук завершил работу?

Структура проекта такая, есть управляющий скрипт, который запускает нескольких пауков

```
s = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(s)
for spider in spider_list:
    process.crawl(spider)
process.start()
```

Я думаю, такое можно реализовать через `scrapy.signals`

```
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class PageSpider(CrawlSpider):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        # some code

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        # some code???????
```

Что надо написть в `spider_closed`, чтобы я мог отследить в управляющем скрипте, что паук отработал? (не через логи)